# call rest service from another rest service using RESTEasy api

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, resteasy, restful-url

**Scenario:** From browser will call RestService- `A` and this `A` service internally calls another RestService-`B`. URL used in browser will have some parameters which are passed to RestService-`B`.

**Q1**. How to call service-B from service-A using java RESTEasy API?
**Q2**. How to pass URL's parameters to service-B from service-A?

Answer (score 0):

In service-A, wrote **"RestEasy client code"** accessing resource/service exists in service-B. From Browser(Firefox), service call(URL) to service-B.